# Webservice working from SOAP UI but not working from PL SQL

Tags: web-services, soap, plsql, soapui

I have a webservice which is working fine when i call it from SOAP UI but do not work when i am calling it from Oracle PLSQL.

Following is my request XML

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:nad="http://MyServer.User.Verification">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <nad:VerifyDetails>
            <nad:xml_request_data>
               &lt;USER_VERIFICATION&gt;
                   &lt;USERNAME&gt;myuser&lt;/USERNAME&gt;
                   &lt;PASSWORD&gt;myPass&lt;/PASSWORD&gt;
               &lt;/USER_VERIFICATION&gt;
            </nad:xml_request_data>
        </nad:VerifyDetails>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

And following is the error message in PLSQL

> The message with Action 'VerifyDetails' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver.  Check that sender and receiver have the same contract and the same binding (including security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have not specified the SOAP action before invoking the web service. You can check the action in the wsdl. Also, make sure that you give the complete path from the action with it and not just the operation name.